# dynamic php zoom image on click of thumbnail

Tags: php, image, zooming, thumbnails, easy-thumbnails

I want to show multiple images on product detail page dynamically in php.I have an image_arr for each product.If I click on any of the thumb images,the zoom image should change.This is what I have tried but I know its not correct as when I click on thumbnail,the image opens in the entire tab replacing my current url and page.

```
    <?php   
          foreach($product_detail as $row):
          $image_arr = $row['product_images'];
          $first_image = $row['product_images'][0]['image_name'];
    ?>
    <div class="col-md-6 single-right-left ">
         <div class="easyzoom easyzoom--overlay easyzoom--with-thumbnails">
              <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/product_detail_images/<?php echo $first_image;?>">
                 <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/product_detail_images/<?php echo $first_image;?>" alt="" class="main-image" />
              </a>
         </div>
         <ul class="thumbnails">
             <?php foreach($image_arr as $curr_img):
                 $prod_image = base_url().'images/product_detail_images/'.$curr_img['image_name'];
             ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $prod_image; ?>" data-standard="images/detail-small-1.png">
                       <img src="<?php echo $prod_image; ?>" alt="" class="thumnail-main" />
                    </a>
               </li>
             <?php endforeach;?>
         </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: may be you need to do that using jquery-zoom . can you check an example here and tell me if you are looking to do something like that : https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Image-Lightbox-with-Zoom-Effect-Zoomify/

Comment: Use Jquery to add a class to the thumbnail, say `zoomed`, set CSS that makes the images bigger if class `zoomed` is set.

Comment: I have used jquery and it works for static contents. I need to make it dynamic. I guess I didn't make my question clear.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will do what my comment suggests. Tailor it for your needs.

```js
$('.image').on('click', function(){
$(this).toggleClass('zoomed');
});
```

```css
.zoomed {
 transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRJRgf_toK_QNtnosM2jkTY3-e4rprTz9DQs8uwI2bSzxp76ho90Q" class="image" />
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTgcNyT2aqDrvJO9CE__3S-8FHg2xRrSbgqYog8iZMZUIacCO3Q" class="image" />
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRj6Pwwf32O7KHMNK_TGQrfhEL05iOjW0GyiPlapAnf9l8oq883" class="image" />
```

Misread the question a bit... so I'll expand...

This snippet will take a click on a thumbnail, and make a separate but related image bigger...

```js
$('.image').on('click', function(){
    var thumbnail = $(this).data('thumbnail');
    $('.thumbnail[data-zoom="image_1"]').toggleClass('zoomed');
});
```

```css
.zoomed {
 transform: scale(1.5);
}

.image  {
width:50px;
height:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTgcNyT2aqDrvJO9CE__3S-8FHg2xRrSbgqYog8iZMZUIacCO3Q" data-thumbnail="image_1" class="image" />
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTgcNyT2aqDrvJO9CE__3S-8FHg2xRrSbgqYog8iZMZUIacCO3Q" data-zoom="image_1" class="thumbnail" />
```